# Microsoft Planner is showing unknown user commented when using API to create task

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

When using Planner API to create task, it shows that an unknown user made a comment for new task but shows last edited was the user that made the API call.
As seen in picture below, it should show medxplanner1 not Unknown... Any ideas?
[image: picture]

Comment: Hopefully you validated the payload, plan, buckets and there is no issue with that?

Comment: This is a UI issue, and we're trying to identify the specific problem here. if you could answer the following questions it would help us find the root cause:  
1- Does refreshing the page fix the issue?  
2- Is the user in question a guest user?  
3- Are there any tenant settings that prevent users from reading group membership or user information?  
4- Is there any reason why the client calls may be blocked? Like tools that are trying to capture/manipulate out going network traffic.  

Thanks!

Comment: @TarkanSevilmis 1. No, 2. No, its a full member, 3. Not as I am aware as the app is multi tenant and submits across different tenants, so far our testing env is fine but the example ones aren't. 4. Shouldn't be, its deployed on azure apps to make api call

Comment: @Dev all validated and works fine on our own tenant

Comment: Does the application/API call is running on app-only context?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: We have made some changes which should improve this. Are you still facing the issue?